# HMVC in codeigniter error with MX_Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

I am start to work with codeigniter HMVC model. I added hmvc extension. but when i run showing

```
Fatal error: Access level to MX_Router::_set_default_controller() must be public (as in class CI_Router) in MX\Router.php
```

Comment: Please update your post with your routes and modules folder structure `$route['default_controller'] = "module-name/controller/index";` and also show us your model

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to setup hmvc

https://github.com/jenssegers/codeigniter-hmvc-modules

Comment: I think he's using one from here https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc